# Footer visible during navigate from Page2 to Page1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, css-transitions

ion-footer button doesn't disappear properly when navigating from page1 to page2 and then navigate back from page2 to page1.

Here's the code in page2:

```
<ion-footer padding>
  <button ion-button block round color="primary">Add to Order</button>
</ion-footer>
```

[image]

I have found an exact same issue on github which recommend adding tag `ion-toolbar` 
 but it didn't work for me:

[ion-footer on back should disappear on willLeave not didLeave](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10680)

[Footer Visible During Navigation Transition](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/8804)

[Nav animations for ion-footer-bar and ion-header-bar](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/nav-animations-for-ion-footer-bar-and-ion-header-bar/55645/19)

Any comments/answers are appreciated!

Comment: From what the comments said, adding a ion-toolbar around the ion-footer should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I mentioned it didn't help. `ion-toolbar` didn't work for others as well in the 3 links I added

Comment: Well, my recommendation is then instead of using a footer, using a div with position fixed at the bottom. It should behave just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class, say, `.app-footer`, with the same CSS properties as `ion-footer` and place the HTML within `ion-content`, like so:

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
  <page code>
  <div class="app-footer">...</div>
</ion-content>
```

**SCSS**

```
.app-footer {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will try it out and let you know!

Comment: Sorry to the late reply, unfortunately, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I make it work, wrap button in div tag with padding solved my issue:

```
<ion-footer>
  <div padding>
  <button
    ion-button block round color="primary"
    [disabled]="items.length === 0" (click)="onContinueClick()">
    Continue
  </button>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: This one worked for me as well! Thanks for sharing Haifeng Zhang!

Answer (score -1):

On ionic version 6 i had the same problem, and for those who are facing the same, the solution that worked for me was enclosing the content of ion-footer into an ion-content
Code example:

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-content>
        Your footer content
    </ion-content>
</ion-footer>
```

In my case i had also to set a height to ion-footer for example:

```
ion-footer{
    height: 6rem;
}
```

Comment: In my case this doesn't work. I need dynamic height to still work since my footer size varies :/